# How do I set an HTTP response header in a seam app?

Tags: seam

I need to set an HTTP response header for all pages in my site and I don't know if seam provides some hooks in a config file to do that, or? Anyone done this before?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find this documented anywhere but by playing with autocompletion in eclipse, editing pages.xml, I found that this works:

```
<page view-id="*">
    <header name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8"/>
```